# Script/cron to automatically renew LetsEncrypt certificates and push to a repository

Tags: git, shell, ssl, lets-encrypt, icinga

I'm looking to have script/cron to be able to renew LetsEncrypt certificates (using acme-tiny) for multiple domains, when an Icinga check says they are 15 days away from expiry.

Then those renewed certificates should be pushed to a GitHub repository.

I'm not sure how to proceed with the script to make it only run for the domain after an Icinga check.

Comment: Are you going to be pushing to a public github repo?

Comment: @PeterReid Yes.

Comment: you should not publically share the private key for your cert, see https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/25437/what-issues-arise-from-sharing-a-ssl-certificates-private-key for a full explantion.

Comment: @PeterReid The private keys are not on GitHub, they are stored on the server. Only the SSL certificates are stored on GitHub.